# 2 Pictures under another

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

I've ran into a little more trouble with the figure environment.

I need to create a table of figures for my documentation and whatever I try I can't get 2 pictures on one page.

As an minimal example, that's as far as I got with searching. Unfortunatly it doesn't work, I only get the Error "Missing Number, treated as Zero" and no pictures showing up.
When I tried to put just 2 figures under another the pictures were just on 2 pages. Some examples showed the subfigure option, so I tried that, but can't get it to work.

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2cm, bottom=4cm, head=58pt]{geometry}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontenc}

\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\section{Table of figures}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Bilder/Net35_Framework_ASP46.png}
        \caption{Installation}
        \label{fig:NET_Framework}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[h]{0.5\textwidth}
         \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Bilder/SQL_Sprache.png}
        \caption{Umstellung}
        \label{fig:SQL_Sprache}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are adding a space between the subfigures, which is just wide enough to cause a line break.  Always add a `%` at the end of a line that ends with a `}`.  (Okay, sometimes the extra spaces are ignored, like after `\par` or `\ignorespaces`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

- the package `subfigure` is obsolete. it is replaced by the package `subfig` which define environment `subfloat`
- better is to use `subcaption` package with `subfigure` environment:

  ```
  \documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{scrartcl}
  \usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2cm,
              bottom=4cm, head=58pt]{geometry}

  \usepackage{subcaption}
  \usepackage{caption}

  \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

  \begin{document}

  \section{Table of figures}
  \begin{figure}[htb]
      \centering
      \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
          \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Bilder/Net35_Framework_ASP46.png}
          \caption{Installation}
          \label{fig:NET_Framework}
      \end{subfigure}

      \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
           \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Bilder/SQL_Sprache.png}
          \caption{Umstellung}
          \label{fig:SQL_Sprache}
      \end{subfigure}
  \caption{main caption}
  \end{figure}

  or

  \begin{figure}[htb]
      \centering
      \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
          \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Bilder/Net35_Framework_ASP46.png}
          \caption{Installation}
          \label{fig:NET_Framework}
      \end{subfigure}\hfill
      \begin{subfigure}{0.49\textwidth}
           \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Bilder/SQL_Sprache.png}
          \caption{Umstellung}
          \label{fig:SQL_Sprache}
      \end{subfigure}
  \caption{main caption}
  \end{figure}
  \end{document}
  ```
- width of the subfigures allows to put two subfigures side-by side.
- however, from question can be understood, that you like to have two figures one top of another. in this case you should remove `subfigure` environments and include two images in one float:

  ```
  \documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{scrartcl}
  \usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2cm,
              bottom=4cm, head=58pt]{geometry}

  \usepackage{caption}
  \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

  \begin{document}

  \section{Table of figures}
  \begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
      \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Bilder/Net35_Framework_ASP46.png}
      \caption{Installation}
      \label{fig:NET_Framework}

       \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{Bilder/SQL_Sprache.png}
      \caption{Umstellung}
   \end{figure}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Comment: The second solution is quite good, but unfortunatly it fails to work whenever I have something other than width=.5\linewidth. Even when there should be enough room to do a .6\linewidth.
Is there anything that could be used to get the width of the images to be automatically calculated so both fit on one page?

Comment: work of solution is independent from width of figures, except if the figures are so height, that two of them can't be placed to one page (in this case you can place only one image per figure. my answer work fine also with images which widths are equal to text width. since i haven't any information about your images, i can't say anything what is going wrong in your real document.

Comment: Ok...
I have 2 Images first is 800x600 and second on is 700x650. Thats why I thought it would be great if Latex could automatically scale the pictures fitting somehow.

Comment: Just for fun:  If you put \section inside a figure [p] you can pack more figures [p] per page.

Comment: Just made i little Screen of this page. https://imgur.com/7djWUmv